# Recommendation on Web scraping and data flow

Tags: raspberry-pi, screen-scraping, smart-tv

I have a solar panel unit, and the company that set it up ([Fronius](http://www.fronius.com/)) has a website where I can live stream the data collected from the solar panel (Current power, Energy today, monthly, and yearly data).

I'd like to display the data from the website in my house, but the smart tv I have won't do full screen on the browser.  I have a raspberry pie, so I thought about instead of using the smart tv, just writing a web scraper to pull the data.  I'm worried that since there is a login to the page, that login might time out, but I'm not sure if that's an issue with scraping or not.

My question is, is there a way to continuously scrape the website to get the updated data in real time, or is there another method that seems better.  If there is a way to continuously scrape, I can work on that on my own, but I really would like to know if there is a better alternative to scraping.

Comment: Which company installed the solar panels? Did you check to see if they provide some sort of API? Also how are *they* getting the data? Presumably the solar panel unit transmits it somehow, if you can find out how the solar unit communicates with the vendor, you may be able to tap into those communications.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  There is no API (to the best of my knowledge), and the company is Fronius.  I'll look into how they are getting the data.

Comment: "Fronius Solar API is an open JSON-interface, based on Ethernet, which is integrated in any Fronius Galvo and Fronius Symo inverter as standard."([Fronius.com](http://www.fronius.com/cps/rde/xchg/SID-7236FB5F-DD08B39F/fronius_international/hs.xsl/83_28911_ENG_HTML.htm#.VByTmS5dVR4)) Does this help at all?

Comment: @lzam I'm 8 years late responding, but your comment did help, and I would accept it as an answer.